# C# How can I pop up Command Prompt(CMD) in running Console?

Tags: c#, .net

In c#, run new process cmd and send out command(ex.. ping 127.0.0.1 -t) to cmd
Then redirect Standardoutput to Console..
But in compile I cannot see cmd which is working in pop up window, only know that command is working on hidden state.
How can I show up command prompt like console pop up?? I want to see console window and command prompt at the same time..

If I don't redirect from cmd and only send the command(ex dir) to cmd,
still command prompt window does't showed up and only see console window..

```
        Process proc_cmd = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startinfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startinfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\";

        startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;//to use RedirectStandard~
        startinfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startinfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        proc_cmd.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        proc_cmd.StartInfo = startinfo;
        proc_cmd.Start();
        proc_cmd.StandardInput.Write(@"ping 127.0.0.1 -t" + 
        Environment.NewLine);
        proc_cmd.StandardInput.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

type [start](https://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm) in command prompt:

```
start
```

This will open up a new cmd window.

Comment: Not just open up a new cmd window. Want to see process of cmd which is running with command in compile. Not in console window.

Comment: Please re-word your question in such as way that it attracts answers that satisfy your needs

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like this if you need to view the console on debug:

```
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
```